# How do I add a Composite primary key with Knex.js?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, composite-primary-key

I have 2 tables. 1 called events with an event ID and another table called tickets which I want to have primary keys of event ID and ticket ID. I am also using a PostgreSQL database. At the moment ,I have it as a foreign key but would like to have it as a primary key in the ticket table with the ticket ID.

```js
knex.schema.createTable('events', function (table) {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('eventName');
});

knex.schema.createTable('tickets', function (table) {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('ticketName');

    table.foreign('tickets').references('events_id').inTable('events');
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As per Knex's documentation [here](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-primary):

> primary — column.primary([constraintName]); table.primary(columns,
> [constraintName]) When called on a single column it will set that
> column as the primary key for a table. If you need to create a
> composite primary key, call it on a table with an array of column
> names instead. Constraint name defaults to tablename_pkey unless
> constraintName is specified.

Therefore, in your case you could add:

```js
table.primary(['name_of_column_1', 'name_of_column_2']);
```

Answer (score 9):

Using your example I think you've got 2 options:

**Option 1 (use the id as primary key and add a unique constraint):**

```js
knex.schema.createTable('events', function (table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('eventName');
});


knex.schema.createTable('tickets', function (table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('ticketName');

    table.integer('event_id').references('id').inTable('events');

    table.unique(['id', 'event_id']);
});
```

**Options 2 (Use the two ids as composite primary keys):**

```js
knex.schema.createTable('events', function (table) {
    table.increments('id').primary();
    table.string('eventName');
});


knex.schema.createTable('tickets', function (table) {
    table.increments('id');
    table.string('ticketName');

    table.integer('event_id').references('id').inTable('events');

    table.primary(['id', 'event_id']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would have left the existing increments field as the primary key, and added an unique index on the foreign key after the table was created.

```js
knex.schema.alterTable('tickets', function(t) {
    t.unique(['events_id'])
})
```

If you want a composite key, do this:

```js
knex.schema.alterTable('tickets', function(t) {
    t.unique(['id','events_id'])
})
```

Comment: but you are not answering the question